# Problem with mesh after rigging

Tags: mesh, rigging

i get problems with mesh after rigging. Maybe someone can help me and tell what i do wrong. You can see details in attached image. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It depends, please upload the file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/)

Comment: Have you applied a 'solidify' modifier? If so, you didn't need it and it's causing at least some of those problems.  Also, from a glance, I can see that normals need to be recalculated and some intensive weight painting needs to be done.

Comment: I am new in blender and it was my first experience in rigging. Maybe you can give advice with some good tutorial what can solve my problem. Thanks in advance Here is model www.pasteall.org/blend/33234 @Leon